# Chain Rule for First Variation?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis

The first variation of a functional, $J(\rho)$, is given by

$\frac{d}{d \epsilon} J(\rho + \epsilon h) |_{\epsilon = 0},$

for functions $\rho, h$ and scalar $\epsilon$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation).  Is there a chain rule for the first variation?  I've only been able to find a couple, unreliable references on this subject online and haven't been able to prove this myself.

Comment: If you want a chain rule for the composition of two functionals $J_1$ and $J_2$, look up the Gateaux derivative (of which the first variation is a special case).